# Does extended support for Ubuntu 14.04 mean it now supports PHP 7.4 or above?

Tags: 14.04, php, versions

With Ubuntu 14.04 extended support being pushed out by another 5 years, does it mean there will now be support for newer versions of PHP such as PHP 7.4? We have not been able to move off PHP 7.2 due to compatibility issues - is this also correct?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: FYI:  CLI tools like `rmadison` let you explore ESM, standard support & development support releases if installed (ie. goes beyond what https://packages.ubuntu.com/ will provide)

Answer (score 3):

14.04 is no longer supported except for [Extended Security Maintenance (ESM)](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm).

ESM provides **critical** updates like bugfixes and security patches.  It generally does not provide feature updates or new versions of software.

ESM also does not receive community support. It is strongly recommended that you install a supported release. ESM is really designed for mission-critical production services where upgrades must undergo vigorous testing to ensure stability.  ESM gives extra time to upgrade to a new release. ESM does not last forever. If you **can** upgrade, you **should** upgrade.

ESM is not really designed for typical Ubuntu users but the basic level of ESM is available free for personal use. If you need more support with ESM beyond that, you will have to pay for support options under a higher tier of service.